# Edit code while debuging in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I've searched for the forum and I have not found how can I edit my code in Visual Studio 2010 when I am debuging.

I mean, in Tools, Edit and Continue is enabled. Also IntelliTrace is disabled, but when I try to change a simple ',' in a SQL command (for example), I can not it and I have to restart de program.

The project is in Framework 4.0.

Comment: I think edit and continue does not work for 64 bit. Are you targeting 32 bit? Also, actually, I still have the same problem with VS 2013, I got used to it by now. For your SQL command, you could e. g. put it into a string, that one you can edit when debugging. Also, the imediate window is helpful.

Comment: What type of project is it? In the past I've found that I cannot edit and continue ASP.NET applications.

Comment: Asp.net projects seems to give me this issue as well. Winforms works perfectly fine editing in debug.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Tools -> Options -> Intellitrace-> General -> Open Intellitrace settings and disable the Collect Call Information setting.

Another solution is to put the Project's Platform target = x86 and not x64.

Comment: Hi, I'm working in X86. Otherwise, in tools, options, intellitrace, general, the checkbox for enable it, is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

1. The configuration is **Debug** and not **Release**;
2. `Enable Optimizations` in `Advance Compile Options` (in Project Properties) is unchecked;
3. `Unmanaged code debugging` is **false** for all referenced projects in the solution;
4. `Embed Interop Types` is **false** and `Copy Local` is **true**.

If it is an ASP.NET project:

1. Right-click the project and select Properties
2. Select the Web tab
3. Check the Enable Edit and Continue checkbox

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What type of VB.NET project?

Comment: Have you checked that the Configuration is `Debug` and not `Release`?

Comment: Yes, the configuration is in debug mode

Comment: Check that you have got `Enable Optizimations` in `Advance Compile Options` (in Project Properties) unchecked.

Comment: Do you have other projects in the solution with unmanaged code debugging switched on? If those projects are referenced from the project that you want to edit and continue on, you will need to turn it off.

Comment: No Diamon, There is only one project in this solution

Answer (score 0):

If there are any DLL Interop embed, does not work.

I have to set to False Embed Interop Types and set to true a copy a local

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

While you are debugging the code, Pause it and press F8 on your keyboard to go step by step
And here's some PICs :

[image: Image : 1]

[image: Image : 2]

[image: Image : 3]

I Hope My Answer Was Useful To You :)

Please... Replay If Unclear

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build-->Configuration Manager and check that Platform is set to x86 (32-bit).  If you use x64 (64-bit) compile, you can't debug/change code on the fly during run-time.